# SQL: How to get the correct resource time for each time record after removed overlap

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have set of machines used record, and there is more than one work piece used on a machine and sometime each record time period are overlapped. Right now I would get the actual time used on each record after removed overlapped time....but that is difficult to me as a SQL beginner....Hope anyone can give me help...thx

The total used time for **CW01** should be **22 hrs** and **EN01** is **8** hrs after removed ovelap time

**Orignal TABLE**

```
   operid    machine   itemid          start_time                  end_time               time_used  
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------      
    454       CW01       31     2017-10-16 08:30:00.000      2017-10-16 16:30:00.000           8
    456       CW01       33     2017-10-16 13:30:00.000      2017-10-16 18:30:00.000           5
    457       CW01       35     2017-10-16 21:30:00.000      2017-10-17 06:30:00.000           9
    458       CW01       36     2017-10-16 15:30:00.000      2017-10-16 23:30:00.000           8
    460       EN01       70     2017-10-16 08:30:00.000      2017-10-16 10:30:00.000           2
    462       EN01       71     2017-10-16 09:30:00.000      2017-10-16 16:30:00.000           7
```

**Desired TABLE**

```
   operid    machine   itemid          start_time                  end_time               time_used  
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------      
    454       CW01       31     2017-10-16 08:30:00.000      2017-10-16 16:30:00.000           6.33333
    456       CW01       33     2017-10-16 13:30:00.000      2017-10-16 18:30:00.000           2.33333
    457       CW01       35     2017-10-16 21:30:00.000      2017-10-17 06:30:00.000           8
    458       CW01       36     2017-10-16 15:30:00.000      2017-10-16 23:30:00.000           5.33333
    460       EN01       70     2017-10-16 08:30:00.000      2017-10-16 10:30:00.000           1.5
    462       EN01       71     2017-10-16 09:30:00.000      2017-10-16 16:30:00.000           6.5
```

Comment: I recommend to do it in some backend language like C#. In SQL Server it will not be efficient. There will be better performance and it will be a little simpler.

Comment: it is not clear how you obtain requested `time_used` values. There are intervals are included in others, however, they still have positive values.

Comment: I have reviewed some examples for remove overlap time in SQL but not exactly what I want, not sure if any special query method can do it easily...since I always see fantastic query statement from this site...just don't know how they made it  :)

Comment: Hi Radim Baca, like the last two row records, item 70 and item 71, there are  9:30 to 10:30 are overlapped, this time period for item 70 and 71 should be 0.5 hour but not 1 hour, the machine worked on these two items at the same time on this period.

Comment: @TerryChan Please clarify in the Desired Table example, where 6.3333 comes from in the first line?

Comment: I would suggest that you ask *another* question.  In that question, ask for a summary for each continuous time period on a machine.  Trying to allocate the overlaps between the rows is an entirely different problem.

Comment: @Cool_Br33ze, for Id 454 first line, there is 5 hours no overlap on other item,  2 hours overlap between Id 456 so it count 1 in actual, 1 hour overlap between 456 and 458 so count it 1/3,  so 5+1+0.333=6.333

Comment: @TerryChan I don't understand why the overlap between 456 and 458 is counted as 1/3

Comment: @Cool_Br33ze, 454, 456 and 458 overlap 1 hour so on 454 it used 1/3 hour on that overlapped period.

Comment: My understanding: Split each time range into minutes (or some other units) and count how many other time ranges include this specific minute, then divide this minute by the number of time ranges this minute "belongs to". Example: minute 2017-10-16 21:30:00.000 belongs to 457 and 458; minute 2017-10-16 13:35:00.000 belongs to 454, 456.

Comment: @Alex, yes, I also think like that before, after try to run on sql it took very long time....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with Q(operid, machine, tm) as(
   -- split rows to time points (start(3), end(4), intersect time (1,2))
   select distinct A.operid,A.machine,
          case N when 1 then (case when A.start_time>B.start_time
                              then A.start_time else B.start_time end)
                 when 2 then (case when A.end_time < B.end_time
                               then A.end_time else B.end_time end)
                 when 3 then A.start_time
                 else A.end_time
          end
     from TabD A
    cross join (select 1 N union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4) N
     left join TabD B
       on B.machine=A.machine and B.operid!=A.operid
      and B.start_time<A.end_time and B.end_time>A.start_time and N.N in(1,2)
)
select operid, machine, sum(time_len)
  from (
   select X.operid, A.machine, s_tm, e_tm,
          datediff(second, s_tm, e_tm)/3600.0/count(1)  time_len
     from (
      -- join time points to intervals
      select operid, machine, tm e_tm,
             lag(tm) over(partition by machine,operid order by tm) s_tm
        from Q
       where Q.tm is not null
     ) X,
       TabD A -- join source rows for interval of time for count it
    where s_tm is not null
      and A.start_time<X.e_tm and A.end_time>X.s_tm
      and A.machine=X.machine
    group by X.operid, A.machine, s_tm, e_tm
  ) Y
group by operid, machine
```

Example on [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/392bf2/1)

Comment: Checked. Sorry first time to use this platform. I appreciate your help! :)